# SQLite: Use x'abc' syntax when creating a table

Tags: sqlite

When inserting values into a SQLite table it is possible to use a syntax like x'41' (=A). This is useful when you try to insert special chars like tabs, newlines etc.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(aColumn VARCHAR(10));
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(x'0a41420a');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test;

AB

sqlite>
```

Is this syntax available for defining the table's name, too?

Something like

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE x'0a41420a'(aColumn VARCHAR(10));
Error: near "x'0a41420a'": syntax error
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x'..'` syntax specifies a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue).
So the value in the table is not a string but a blob, unless you explicitly [convert](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) it into a string:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(CAST(x'0a41420a' AS TEXT));
```

In SQL, identifiers (such as table/column names) can be quoted with double quotes. Inside a quoted identifer, all characters (except the zero byte) are allowed (but double quotes must be doubled):

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "
AB
"(cols);
sqlite> SELECT hex(name) FROM sqlite_master;
0A41420A
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification with the x'..' syntax.

You're right, starting with a double quote I can use newlines. 

But how about a tab (or more uncommon white space chars like \v, \r, \f…)? It seems to be impossible to use a tab inside the sqlite command line shell (even after starting with a double quote). Is there another solution, e.g. writing their hex values (=ascii representation; that's what I thought the x'..' syntax could be used for)?

Comment: Every character is possible, that's true. Did not work directly in my sqlite command shell, but it works when I create an input file and pipe it to the command shell.